# Mouse not working properly after using AnyDesk for long time

Tags: mouse, remote-access, anydesk

I have AnyDesk installed on my work computer (Desktop PC, Windows 10 Pro). During home quarantine, I've connected to the work computer from home (Windows 10 Home edition) using AnyDesk, every day, for 6-8 (literally :)) hours every time.

It worked fine, without any problem.

However, now that I'm back at the office and using the work computer, the mouse is "losing clicks" (left clicking just doing nothing). At first 50% of the clicks were lost, after restart it's about 10% but it's still very annoying.

The mouse was working perfectly before, so I'm pretty sure something with the AnyDesk usage is causing this.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried another mouse to be 100% sure that your work mouse is not the problem?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio no, not yet - want to go the software path first.

Comment: same problem. it is so annoying. all permissions are granted. IDK what else to do.

Comment: @Sergio well in my case, using a new mouse "solved" the problem and so far it didn't happen again. But I still think AnyDesk caused the mouse to break somehow, so I am waiting for answer here.